# creating a class, beginning to use OOP. java program doesn't display anything?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, constructor

The main problem is that nothing happens when I run my program, but there aren't any bugs. My program is supposed to create a new class (`Fraction`) with a few methods that will manipulate the fraction and test it with a few different values. It's a two file program I'm having a bit of trouble with the constructor methods.

I created a method that is supposed to initialize the numerator and denominator of the object, but I don't know what to put inside the definition. The numbers for the object are chosen in the test file.

Here's that piece:
(located in the file where I defined the class and all of the methods for it)

```
public Fraction(int n, int d)
{
    //not sure what values to enter below
    numerator = ;
    denominator = ;
}
```

I'm also not sure I did the loops correctly, because nothing happens when I run the program, it just says "Build Successful". I tried putting in a confirmation dialog box, but do I still need to initialize the program?

Below is the full code.
first file in program:

```
public class Fraction {

private int numerator;
private int denominator;
//returns the fraction
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return numerator + "/" + denominator;
}
//turns fraction into decimal
public double getDecimal()
{
    double decimal = numerator / denominator;
    return decimal;
}
//reduces fraction. doesn't return value
public void reduce()
{
    int gcf = 1, smaller;
    if (numerator < denominator)
    {
        smaller = numerator;
    } else
    {
        smaller = denominator;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= smaller; i++)
    {
        if (numerator % i == 0 && denominator % i == 0)
        {
            gcf = i;
        }
    }
    numerator = numerator / gcf;
    denominator = denominator / gcf;
    System.out.print(numerator + "/" + denominator);
}
//turns fraction into a mixed number and returns the new value
public String toMixed()
{
    int whole = numerator / denominator;      
    numerator %= denominator;
    String changedFraction = (whole + " " + numerator + "/" + denominator);
    return changedFraction;
}

public Fraction(int n, int d)
{
    //subbed in zeros below so it doesn't give me an error
    numerator = 0;
    denominator = 0;
}

//initializes the fraction to 1. Not sure how to call this method in the test file. 

   public Fraction()
   {
       numerator = 1;
       denominator = 1;
   }
}
```

second (test) file:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestProgram
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{  
    //dialog box that runs program until user chooses to exit
    int option = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
    while (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
 //menu that lets user choose which method they want to test the values with
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose"
            + "\n" + "1. Test the toString() method"
            + "\n" + "2. Test the getDecimal() method"
            + "\n" + "3. Test the reduce() method"
            + "\n" + "4. Test the toMixed() method"
            + "\n" + "Click cancel to quit");
    int choice = Integer.parseInt(input);

    //array that holds 5 test values
    Fraction[] fractionArray = new Fraction[4];

    fractionArray[0] = new Fraction(9, 12);
    fractionArray[1] = new Fraction(31, 2);
    fractionArray[2] = new Fraction(12, 9);
    fractionArray[3] = new Fraction(12, 120);
    fractionArray[4] = new Fraction(16, 53);

    //calls the method chosen
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <fractionArray.length; i++)
        {
            fractionArray[i].toString();
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <fractionArray.length; i++)
        {
            fractionArray[i].getDecimal();
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <fractionArray.length; i++)
        {
            fractionArray[i].reduce();
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 4)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <fractionArray.length; i++)
        {
            fractionArray[i].toMixed();
        }
    }
    //initializes the constructor method. not sure what values to put below.
       Fraction currentFraction = new Fraction(2,3);

    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Continue?");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you want

```
public Fraction(int n, int d)
{
    //subbed in zeros below so it doesn't give me an error
    numerator = n;
    denominator = d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the way you are using JOptionPane in your main.

First of all I think you should create a parent JFrame for the Pane.

Secondly I think JOptionPane.showOptionDialog method is more suited for what you are trying to achieve here, if I understand it correctly.

This is a pretty good guide on how to make dialogs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html